# How to update my version of Ruby from terminal?

Tags: ruby

I ran the command 'ruby -v' on my Linux Mint 10 virtual machine and got:

```
stapiagutierrez@Sergio-Linux-VM ~/Desktop/Tickets/tickets $ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]
```

How can I upgrade it to the latest version, 1.9.2?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question: This is software related and meets the last two bullets in the SO FAQ: "* software tools commonly used by programmers" and "*
matters that are unique to the programming profession".

Answer (score 33):

I would suggest using [RVM](http://rvm.io/). That way you can keep the 1.8.7 version of Ruby, but you can also install new ones easily:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

And switch between them with no effort:

```
rvm 1.8.7
rvm 1.9.2
```

Using rvm you can set your default version of Ruby like this:

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2
```

Comment: I would recommend: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ which has documentation on installing RVM and setting system defaults. The quick way is: bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, It is VERY important to read the entire `install` page and do the "Post Install" section. Too many people miss that. Also, read the [Rubygems](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/) page, especially the "DO NOT use sudo..." section.

Comment: +1 for RVM. Using Ubuntu repositories (and probably Mint) leads to endless mis-configured paths and lost gems.

Comment: Incidentally, for those who use GNU `screen`, check [this](https://rvm.io/workflow/screen) out.

Comment: If you get "RVM is not a function" error check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752779/rvm-is-not-a-function-error